# UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions undeclared

Tags: iphone

Greetings!

I'm attempting to build an iPhone application that makes use of an iOS4-only function: 'UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions'.

I'm building for iPhone device 3.1.3 in XCode 3.2.1 and getting errors about that function not being defined.

[This stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607082/checking-if-uigraphicsbeginimagecontextwithoptions-is-supported) already showed me that I should link weakly against UIKit and check that function for NULL, I am already doing this:

[image]
[image]

However, build still fails with:
[image]

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build against the iOS 4.x SDK, otherwise the compiler has no knowledge of that function.